# How to store Android application data/settings in RAD Studio XE6 using C++?

Tags: android, c++, save, c++builder-6

I figured out that one of the easiest way to store simple data are probably SharedPreferences, but it won't work in RAD Studio XE6 with C++. Do I really have to make a database for such trivial things like text area and few checkboxes? Please help me, I'm the beginner.

Comment: I have no experience with RAD Studio XE6, but if it forces you to move such business logic from Java to C++, then you should reconsider using it. Not using `SharedPreferences` and rolling your own persistent-storage system is unacceptable. How exactly does it "not work", anyway?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well, it is *possible* that it works, but I'm just a newbie and I have no idea how to use it with c++, instead of Java. I hoped that someone experienced with making mobile apps in this program will tell me how he stores data in the simplest way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, no one could answer me, but I have found an answer myself. I used ClientDataSet item and now I can make fields with it and export any string, int, boolean etc. to the *.xml file.